# Set Theory proof from "How to Prove It"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having difficulties with this proof--Hints will be appreciated.

Prove that for any sets $A$ and $B$, if $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) =  \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ then either $A$ is a subset of $B$ or $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: I assume that P is being used as power set notation, not as probability, yes?  Consider the contrapositive statement then, if $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$, then that says that there is some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $a\notin B$ and $b\notin A$.  What can you say about the subset $\{a,b\}$ then?

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!(that was subtle)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** We have $A\cup B\in\mathcal P(A\cup B)$. By hypothesis $\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)=\mathcal P(A\cup B)$, we obtain $A\cup B\in\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$. Now, by definition of union, we have $A\cup B\in\mathcal P(A)$ or $A\cup B\in\mathcal P(B)$, and so $A\cup B\subseteq A$ or $A\cup B\subseteq B$ by definition of power set. In particular, we know that $A\subseteq A\cup B$ and $B\subseteq A\cup B$; thus the claim follows.

Comment: _+1_ although I don't see how this is a "hint" :-)

Comment: Missing the obvious statements: why $A\cup B\in\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ (start) and why $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$ (end). Indeed, now I think it is not a hint. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that we have the assumption but neither of the inclusions holds. Then $A \nsubseteq B$ so there is some $a \in A, a \notin B$ and also $B \nsubseteq A$ and so there is some $b \in B, b \notin A$. Now consider $\{a,b\} \subseteq A \cup B$, so $\{a,b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 1):

As $A \cup B \in \mathcal{P} (A \cup B) = \mathcal{P} (A ) \cup \mathcal{P} (B)$ it follows that $A \cup B \in \mathcal{P} (A)$ or $A \cup B \in \mathcal{P} (B)$.

Thus $A \cup B \subset A$ or $A \cup B \subset B$. Therefore  $B \subset A \cup B \subset A$ or $A \subset A \cup B \subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I was confused by the question until I noticed the following. When you think of $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ watch out. It isn't true that:

$$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) = \{\alpha \cup \beta: \alpha \subset A, \beta \subset B\}$$

but rather

$$\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) = \{\alpha: \alpha \subset A  \ or \  \alpha \subset B \}.$$